# Prevent Incrementing

Tags: java

I have a somewhat trivial issue at hand. So I'm trying to stop my counter, c, from incrementing the for loop. I'm trying to fill in a spot in the pond ONLY if its empty. If its already filled with another fish (white or red), I don't want the counter to increment. Once a spot (or element rather) in the pond is filled, it can't be filled again. So it should have 500 white fishes and 5 red fishes by the end.

I feel as if I'm using the wrong conditional statement to approach this problem. Once my counter increments, so does my while statement that called the method, placeFish, increments the white or red counters as well, which is not what I want to do. I keep getting total amounts of white/red fishes that are not 500 nor 5, but rather lower because the while counters are increasing when ideally I don't want them to.

Am I correct in using a for statement? I tried while, but it didn't seem to work either.

```
public static void fishes (int[][] pond) {
            //pond has dimensions [50][50] in a different method that call fishes
            //every element in the 2D array pond is already set to value 0
    int whitefish = 500;
    int redfish= 5;
    int whitefishvalue = 1
    int redfishvalue = 2
    int white = 0;
    int red = 0;
    while (white < whitefish)
    {
        placeFish (pond, whitefishvalue);
        white++;
    }
    while (red < redfish) 
    {
        placeFish (pond redfishvalue);
        redd++;
    }
}

public static void placeFish(int[][] pond, int newFish) {
    int a = random.nextInt(pond.length);
    int b = random.nextInt(pond[0].length);
            int spot = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < 1; c++)
    {
        if (pond [a][b] == spot)
        {
            pond[a][b] = newFish;
            c++;
                    //How to stop c++ from incrementing?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems a bit off that you wouldn't want to increment a value through a loop in this manner.  Could you explain more what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I think this is what you want... this will randomly search through the array looking for a spot and it will stop when you find one, then it places the fish there.

```
public static void placeFish(int[][] pond, int newFish) {
    int spot = 0;
    int a;
    int b;

    do
    {
        a = random.nextInt(pond.length);
        b = random.nextInt(pond[0].length);
    } while (pond [a][b] != spot);

    pond[a][b] = newFish;
}
```

Comment: @Sozziko: Glad I could help. Just remember, don't write code just because it worked last time, plan what you're trying to do first and then write that. Your question is about "preventing incrementing" but you actually didn't need to have a counter at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int c = 0; c < 1; c++) {
    if (pond [a][b] == spot) {
        pond[a][b] = newFish;
        c++; //How to stop c++ from incrementing?
    }
}
```

You actually increment `c` twice in this loop, which I'm guessing is not what you meant to do. The first place is in the first line. Remember that a `for` loop, generically written as

```
for (initialize; condition; increment) {
    // stuff goes here
}
```

is just equivalent to the `while` loop

```
initialize;
while (condition) {
    // stuff goes here
    increment;
}
```

So at the end of each iteration of the loop, it automatically increments `c`.

The other place you increment `c` is in the body of the `if` statement. That only happens when `pond[a][b] == spot`. So on iterations where that's true, you increment `c` twice in total, once in this `if` statement and once at the end of the loop.

I'm guessing you would like to only increment once when `pond[a][b] == spot` and not at all otherwise, right? If so, it's an easy fix: just remove the incrementing statement that runs at the end of every loop iteration.

```
for (int c = 0; c < 1;) {
    // stuff goes here
}
```

That way you're left with only the one increment line in the `if` statement.

---

By the way, do note that there's no point in using a `for` loop that only ever has one iteration.

Comment: Sorry I was actually writing out the code from memory as I do not currently have my laptop with me. So I'm working on my assignment by hand and copying it over to eclipse afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is quite confusing, but I'm assuming you don't want your for loop to increment every time?

```
for (int c = 0; c < 1;) //It's not necessary to put an increment there.  You can in fact write a loop like for(;;) and escaping it via break
{
    if (pond [a][b] == spot)
    {
        pond[a][b] = newFish;
        c++;
                //How to stop c++ from incrementing?
    }
}
```